# How to unsubscribe from an RxJS 5 observable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, rxjs5

I have been using this pattern:

```
func myObservable() Observable<boolean> {
    ...
}

func myFunc() {
    myObservable().subscribe((cond: boolean) => {
        if (cond) {
            // How do I unsubscribe here?
        }
    });
}
```

However I can't see any way to unsubscribe thereby maybe creating a memory leak.

The reason I ask is because [Angular 2's HTTP client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) uses the same pattern - although I believe it auto-unsubscribes somehow and I would like to do the same.

Comment: You need to store the return value which is a `Subscription` and unsubscribe from that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
func myFunc() {
   var subscription = myObservable().subscribe((cond: boolean) => {
       if (cond) {
          // How do I unsubscribe here?
           subscription.unsubscribe()
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: I did not know you could successfully capture a value within a function that isn't declared until after the function is constructed. Most languages will not allow that. Thanks.

Comment: That's a callback which is practically is another function that is invoked later on definite event